# Geometry : unable to change page size

Tags: margins, geometry, size, page

I am trying to work on a paper with specific size : 240mm x 160 mm.
To generate my paper I am using pdflatex from texlive.

I used to do this :

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \pdfpageheight=240mm
  \pdfpagewidth=160mm
\else
  \special{papersize=240mm,160mm}
\fi
```

It was working perfectly, but it is not compatible with TikZ (see my previous [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536486/tikz-messing-up-page-size?r=SearchResults&s=1|84.1614)).

Someone told me to use geometry: unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.
Here is my rather simple code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm]{geometry}

\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the page is not correctly shaped... 
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why are you messing with `\pdfpage...` geometry will do that for you, has done for years

Comment: And don't ignore errors. You cannot load `geometry` twice where the first is without options and the latter is with options.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I havent seen the double geometry loading... I must have been working on this for too long ! It is all good now, thanks again.

Comment: Well I did get a big fat error when I tried your MWE.

Comment: Don't remove your mistake from the MWE, then your question will no longer make any sense

Comment: Note we rolled back your edit so the question still makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ignore compilation errors

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm]{geometry}160mm]{geometry}
```

gives an option class error. Remove the first line and the generated PDF has the correct size

Comment: Thank you, my bad ! I am working on an online editor which is not showing compilation errors.

Comment: @Guliup may I ask which online editor? No respectful online editor hides compilation errors